# mockito donothing for method with arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

```
class A{
     public void aa(B b){}
     public void bb(){}
}
```

For mocking method `bb()` I used `doNothing().when(A).bb();`.

What should I use for function `aa()` Since it has arguments.

Comment: `doNothing().when(A).aa(Matchers.any());` you should read [the doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

Comment: Good to know...

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, you shouldn't need `doNothing`, since mocks by default do "nothing" when their methods are called.  You would only need to write `doNothing` if you are working with a *spy* instead of a *mock*.

In Mockito 1.x, you can write

```
doNothing().when(yourSpyGoesHere).aa(any(B.class));
```

which effectively disables any call to `aa`.

The meaning of `any` was changed in Mockito 2, so you now need to write `nullable` instead of `any`.

```
doNothing().when(yourSpyGoesHere).aa(nullable(B.class));
```

Comment: Plesae see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808166/donothing-does-not-work-when-i-want-to-mock-data-and-test-ui-fragment